# ImportError: No module named 'bootstrapform'

Tags: django, python-3.x

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/home/etudiant/git/leasing/leasing/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'bootstrapform'
```

Comment: Did you install `django-bootstrap-form`? (`pip install django-bootstrap-form`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may need to install `django-bootstrap-form` as follows:

```
pip install django-bootstrap-form
```